# imagemagick crop error option requires an argument -crop

Tags: command-line-interface, crop, imagemagick-convert

i want to bulk crop image so i thought i use imagemagick but when i run this command on the command line:

```
convert src.jpg -gravity center -crop '290×310+50+50' src_c.jpg
```

this's error message:

```
convert: option requires an argument `-crop' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1087.
```

what's the problem here.

**im on ubuntu 11.04 and i'm using imagemagick 6.6.2**

any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experiments your x in `290×310+50+50` isn't actually an x (The letter X, rather than a multiplication symbol). Change it to an x (as in the letter) and it works for me

Comment: Thanks, that worked. i just copied it from a website and paste it to the command line thanks again.

Comment: No worries, stumped me for a bit to!